# Read from dummy file 4 bytes at a time

Tags: c++

Trying to read from a file 4 bytes at a time and I can't figure out exactly how to adjust the parameters of ifstream.read() to get it working.

(As a side note: the file ("dummy.txt") is simply a dummy file created through Windows command line "fsutil.exe", so there aren't any actual integers in the file.)

```
//Benchmark Program in C++
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <time.h>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    clock_t t1,t2;
    t1=clock();
    int temp;
    int myint;
    ifstream fstr;
    fstream dummy("dummy.txt", ios::binary);
    while(!dummy.eof()) {
        temp = fstr.read(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&myint), sizeof(int));
    }
    cout << "Hard Drive Benchmark"
         << endl;
    t2=clock();
    float diff ((float)t2-(float)t1);
    float seconds = diff / CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
    cout << "Time Taken: " << seconds << " seconds" <<endl;
}
```

The errors I receive are:

> C:\Users\Tai\Desktop\File-Benchmark.cpp||In function 'int main()':|
>   C:\Users\Tai\Desktop\File-Benchmark.cpp|15|
>   error: invalid user-defined conversion from 'std::basic_istream::__istream_type {aka std::basic_istream}' to 'int' [-fpermissive]|
>   c:\program files (x86)\codeblocks\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\4.8.1\include\c++\bits\basic_ios.h|115|
>
> note: candidate is: std::basic_ios<_CharT, _Traits>::operator void*() const [with _CharT = char; _Traits = std::char_traits] |
>   c:\program files (x86)\codeblocks\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\4.8.1\include\c++\bits\basic_ios.h|115|
>
> note:   no known conversion for implicit 'this' parameter from 'void*' to 'int'|
>   ||=== Build failed: 1 error(s), 0 warning(s) (0 minute(s), 0 second(s)) ===|

Comment: does your code work? If not what goes wrong?

Comment: @pm100 it does not - I get a few compile errors, I'll add them to the post.

Comment: i would use fread - that feels like the right kind of thing for byte fiddling

Comment: `sizeof(myint)` is not necessary 4 bytes. Also you must precise what you mean by byte. Cannonical byte = 8bits, but in compiler terms byte may also mean `sizeof(char)`, which is not necessary 8 bits.

Comment: fstr.read returns the stream not an int http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/istream/istream/read/

Comment: That snippet is totally weird, please do not troll around and grab some documentation.

Comment: iostreams really are made for text I/O, not binary (there's a character conversion applied to *all* functions, even "unformatted" ones, which can be customized pretty heavily but never disabled).  Not to mention being an order of magnitude slower than stdio.h functions, which in turn are slower than the OS I/O API.  So I'd recommend using something else for binary I/O.

Comment: @BenVoigt hmmmm, are characters affected even if using `read()` and `write()` functions? Thought `ios::binary` makes at least some sense....

Comment: @doc: Yes, unformatted functions like `read` and `write` are affected, though for narrow streams the character conversion doesn't do anything.

Comment: @MooingDuck: I've never been able to find any guarantee in the Standard that there isn't OEM->ANSI conversion, or ASCII->UTF-8 (or ASCII->EBCDIC for that matter).  All a "narrow" stream means is that the program side of the conversion is a `char` type.  The file side could be anything.  And I have looked for such a guarantee.

Comment: @doc: Pure and simply, it is named badly.  `ios::binary` actually means "disable newline translation", nothing more.

Answer (score 4):

I'd write the loop like so:

```
uint32_t myint;
while(fstr.read(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&myint), sizeof(myint))) {
    // do something with myint
}
```

- Use sizeof on the actual object (minimize chances of getting it wrong)
- be aware of architectural differences (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness)
- The eof check is rarely useful. It's only useful *after* an error has been detected (to figure out whether a specific extraction failed - so you can try something else - or the stream's end was reached)
- The contextual converion to boolean of the `stream` object is intended for easy error diagnostics

Comment: `sizeof(myint)` is not necessary 4 bytes.

Comment: so to be clear the condition in the while loop recasts the "space" character as an int - and then reads it in from the file? Or am I misinterpreting it?

Comment: The condition just checks whether reading 4 bytes succeeded. The `read()` call however, it reads the bytes into the memory area pointed to by the pointer `&myint` (type `int*`). Since that's not the type required by `read` (it requires `char*`) we need to cast it. Only few re-interpretation casts like this are actually allowed by the C++ standard (mostly, compilers are free to do all kinds of proprietary stuff in cases not involving `char*`). Be careful playing with `reinterpret_cast`.